# I want show the confirmation message before deleting a data using checkbox

Tags: php

I have a problem displaying the confirmation message before deleting a data

```
if(isset($_POST['del'])){
        echo "
            <script>
                var x;
                    x = confirm ('You want to proceed deleting?');

                    if(x == true){";
            for($i=0;$i<$_SESSION['count'];$i++){
            $checkbox = $_POST['checkbox'];
            $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT picture FROM tblreserve WHERE id='$del_id'");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $del_pic = $row['picture'];
            }
            $sql = "DELETE FROM tblreserve WHERE id = $del_id";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if($result){
                if(is_file($del_pic)){
                        unlink($del_pic);
            }
    }
    }
    header('location:view.php');

                    echo "}
                    else{
                        location.href = 'view.php';
                        }
                    </script>";
    }
```

Comment: You seem to be mixing JavaScript and PHP, that doesn't work; at least not like this. Look into AJAX.

Comment: _"I have a problem"_ And the exact problem is...?

Comment: also the echo statement is missing a closing doublequote

Comment: A useful tip is simply trying to echo out your statements and see if it prints what you intend it to. Overall though, directly injecting HTML/JS with PHP echos is bad style. You should be taking advantage of the fact that PHP allows you to switch PHP on and off with `<?php ?>`

Comment: @XaxD sorry sir, i am still a newbie in php . hope u understand

Comment: @j08691 i want to show a confirmation message before i delete the date in my table.

Comment: @aug i've done it, i tried to erase the statement in deleting data, then i remain the confirmation message and it appears the confirmation, but when i tried to put the statement back the, confirmation mesage did not appear, what shoudl i do sir?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use JavaScript to control what PHP is output, as the PHP is executed on the server side, whereas the JavaScript is executed by the client, you can however integrate confirmation into your delete buttons using JavaScript like the example below:

```
<button onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) window.location = 'some_other_page.php'">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the confirmation box prompted in your browser, all your php code is all parse in the file. Delete the data in mysql is via php, so you want to confirm this by clicking the javascript prompted button, you should refresh your page by sending a tag in from url, or you can implement it via ajax.
In you given snippet, php can not be halted there by the javascript confirm. You should know one is server end, the other is client-end

Comment: i am new in php, i made it when i use include()but another problem occured when the user click the confirm button the data still remain but when i click edit button after the 1st attempt in deleting the one which i had check was the one being deleted.